# Jump height and gravity in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and use `CharacterController.Move` to move my character around. In my game world, 1 unit = 1 meter.
This works great, for example for speed: if I use a speed of 5, the character has a speed of 5m/s.

I make my character jump using:

```
if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
moveDirection.y = jumpHeight;
...
moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
```

This works fine too, but since the gravity is pulling my character down, the jumpHeight isn't actually reached. For example, a jumpHeight of 8 result in a jump of something around 2.4 meters.

How can I change my code so jumpHeight represents the height the character will jump, even with the gravity pulling him down? Basically, with a jumpHeight of 8, I want my player to perform a jump of 8 meters.

According to physics, with an initial velocity of 8, the height would be 1.6 with a gravity of 20 (`height = initialvelocity^2/(2*gravity)`). If this indeed would be the height I'm seeing in-game, I could simply transform the formula, but I'm seeing a height of around 2.4 meters...

Comment: Have you thought about some solution using vector3.slerp?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. I'm assuming you know the SUVAT equations.

Our knowns can be jumpheight (8) and timeToJumpApex (0.5f) <- You can change this to whatever, but 0.5f is a good start.

Time to jump apex is as the name implies, the time taken to hit the apex of a jump.

We now need to solve for the remaining variables needed, gravity and jump velocity. Gravity can be defined as such:

```
gravity = 2 * jumpheight / timeToJumpApex^2;
```

Jump velocity can be defined as such:

```
jumpVelocity = gravity * timeToJumpApex;
```

Then you can do:

```
if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
moveDirection.y = jumpVelocity;
...
moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
```